# How to hide groupbox if a certian treeview nodes are selected?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have several Groupboxes hidden or un-enabled when certain treeview nodes are selected. I found the code to make this work, but only for one node. I have tried many things to make it work but, No Luck.

I tried adding the different Node names in this line but it didn't work.

```
If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "Preps","Food","Skills" Then
```

This is my current code-

```
 `    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles     TreeView1.AfterSelect
    GroupBox2.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text + " " + "Input"
    Label18.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text + " " + "Inventory"
    GroupBox3.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text + " " + "Stored Totals"
    If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "Preps" Then
        GroupBox2.Enabled = False
        Panel1.Enabled = False
        GroupBox3.Enabled = False
    Else
        GroupBox2.Enabled = True
        Panel1.Enabled = True
        GroupBox3.Enabled = True
    End If
 End Sub`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: So you want to “or” conditions together or maybe where “inlist”?

Comment: That is what I needed! Thank you so much!